# PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal making the solution less accurate?

Tags: differential-equations, precision-and-accuracy

I am having this differential equation:

```
Sweird = NDSolve[{1/Sqrt[1 - (8/10) Exp[-(y[t]^2)/2]] == y'[t], 
   y[0] == -5}, {y}, {t, 0, 10}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

And I plot it:

```
ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[{y[t], t} /. Sweird], 
  Evaluate[{y'[t], t} /. Sweird], 
  Evaluate[{y[t], (1/y'[t])} /. Sweird]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: plot at accuracy and precision at 10]

Which if one sees the differential equation, makes all the sense to look at least qualitatively as the right solution. But when I decide to increase the accuracy and precision, I get a warning message:

```
Sweird = NDSolve[{1/Sqrt[1 - (8/10) Exp[-(y[t]^2)/2]] == y'[t], 
   y[0] == -5}, {y}, {t, 0, 10}, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 20]
```

> NDSolve::ndtol: Tolerances requested by the AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal options could not be achieved at t == 0.`.

The solution graph now loses all its distinct features, and it also shows a few warnings that I am not sure if they are related:

[image: plot with accuracy and precision of 20]

Any insight into what is going on here? I wouldn't have expected the accuracy and precision to have such impact on the solution. Maybe I am missing something very obvious, but I can't see what that is.

Comment: Try setting the `WorkingPrecision` considerably higher than `MachinePrecision`, which is about 16 digits.  You can't get higher than `$MachinePrecision` with the default, and usually it is several digits below that, for numerics reasons.  (For instance, according to the documentation, the default `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` is 1/2 of `WorkingPrecision`, which gives a generic heuristic estimate.)

Comment: `MachinePrecision` doesn't seem to be a valid option for `NDSolve`

Comment: `MachinePrecision` or `WorkingPrecision`?  It should be the latter. -- As in [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)